# jquery bind event to new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, event-handling

JAVA SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".group").click(groupFile);

     function groupFile(){
        alert('clicked!');
     }
});
function insert()

{
    $("body").append("<div class='group' ></div>");
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='group' >
</div>

<input type="button" value="insertNewElement" id="insert" onclick="insert()"/>
```

when page loaded,on click  `div.group` works well and fire `groupFile` and alert to me.
but when inserted the new `div.group`.onclick `div.group` function `groupFile` does not worked?
please help me

Comment: `$("<div class='group' ></div>").click(groupFile).appendTo("body");` <-- If you don't want delegation, just bind directly to the new element you're creating. There's no need to select it when you have it right there.

Comment: ...but you'll need to put your `groupFile()` function outside of the `.ready()` callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method to delegate the events to a static ancestor as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on("click",".group",groupFile);
 function groupFile(){
    alert('clicked!');
 }
});
```

read more about [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Get rid of the `$(document).ready()` part. Doesn't make sense to wait for the document to load if you're binding to the document. That way clicks will trigger the handler even if the page hasn't finished loading. If you're going to use that level of delegation, might as well get the most out of it.

Comment: @squint That's a good point... But that'll leave the handler function in global scope... I don't know whether that makes a difference or not, but currently it looks like OP wants some functions inside `ready()` and some outside... not sure why, otherwise I would've changed the named handler to an anonymous function... :)

Comment: Yeah... that's true. I'd probably throw it in an IIFE if that's the case, but I guess we don't know what else is going on there. I'm betting that the OP is throwing code around without much organization, but we don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should delegate event to `BODY` (or document or 'usually' better to the closest static parent element) level. Using `.on()`, pass `selector` param as it:

```
$('body').on('click', 'div.group', function(){
     //...
});
```

[See explanation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: @Omar Oh ya, of course, thx for the hint! :)

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic elements you need to bind to event on the body:

```
$("body").on("click", ".group", function(e){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: You don't "need to" bind to the body. It's merely one option.